# plugin:vite:import-analysis Failed to resolve import "store/hooks" from src folder

Tags: testing, cypress, vite, src

In the cypress12.3 when trying to run cypress component testing, on the runner, I got this error.

[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "store/hooks" from "src\components\integration\List.tsx". Does the file exist?

This error doesn't happen on cypress10.x.

I confirmed src folder is there, and also confirmed tsconfig.json file set correctly for src folder.